# Chartjs not picking up twig variable for label

Tags: javascript, symfony, twig, chart.js, frontend

I am trying to get my labels in my chart to appear based on my query on the back end.  This is what my javascript looks like right now.

```
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: ['C00891', 'C01013', 'C00364', 'A00152', 'C00985'],
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Top 5 Dealerships By Earn',
                data: [{% for key, value in info %}{% if not loop.first %},{% endif %}{{ value['total']|e }} {% endfor %}],
                backgroundColor: [
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
                ],
                borderColor: [
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                ],
                borderWidth: 1
            }]
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    });
```

My data: loop works and I am able to pass in my twig variable and update the data.  When I try to do this with the label

```
label: {% for value in info %}{{ value['d_id']|e }} {% endfor %}
```

My chart does not load.

id like to be able to pass in my variable to my twig template dynamically as well, just like the data.

Any ideas?

My twig variable is set like this and it passes the data from my php (symfony) controller

```
{% set info = data %}
```

Comment: So which error does the console throw? I imagine `value['d_id']` is a string?

Comment: I wish it would throw some sort of error but the chart doest load when I add the twig loop inside the label attribute.  When I take it out and hard code it, it loads again.@DarkBee

Comment: yeah but the labels are strings? You'll need to place quotes around it then

Comment: Ok, this is the error(was looking at the wrong console).  
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` @DarkBee

Comment: btw, that was it @DarkBee, I was too close to the project that I couldnt see.  thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case that anyone runs into this, you have to put quotes around the value like DarkBee stated.  In my case it was

```
{% for value in info4 %}'{{ value['d_id']|e }}',{% endfor %}
```